# 3-column layout to 2-column layout with minimum markup changes

Tags: html, css, layout, less, multiple-columns

In an app I am maintaining, I am implementing less (the styling language) changes for iPad form factors.  I've already got media queries set up to handle this, but I have a slight problem with getting my markup to behave!

Currently, in our 'normal' form factor, we have a 3-column layout:

```
*---*-----*---*
| A |  B  | C |
*---*-----*---*

<div class="lft-side-panel">
    A
</div>

<div class="ctr-panel">
    B
</div>

<div class="rt-side-panel">
    C
</div>

.lft-side-panel {
    .span4();   // 4/16 slots wide
    margin-left: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.ctr-panel {
    .span8();
}

.rt-panel {
    .span4();
}
```

However, due to size constraints on these smaller form factors, I am trying for a 2-column setup as such:

```
*---*---------*
| A |         |
*---*    B    |
| C |         |
*---*---------*

<div class="lft-side-panel">
    A
</div>

<div class="ctr-panel">
    B
</div>

<div class="rt-side-panel">
    C
</div>

/* These appear to be where the solution lies, at least as far as Less is concerned. */
.lft-side-panel,
.rt-side-panel {
    left: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    .span4();
}

.ctr-panel {
    span12();
}
```

I've tried

1. specifying a `top` and `left` attribute with value 0 for the C div,
2. specifying `float: left` in the media query for the `rt-side-pnl` class

...but it leaves me with a layout like:

```
*---*-----*
| A |     |
*---|  B  |
    |     |
*---*-----*
| C |
*---*
```

**Question:** What am I missing to achieve a 2-column layout with A and C on top of each other, and B off to the side?  I have a feeling the solution is right under my nose, but I'm just not seeing it.  If possible, I must preserve the structure of the markup; if I must re-order things slightly, that can work too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/s756e/3/
I set `.rt-side-panel, .lft-side-panel { float:left; width=25%;}` (needed to convert your 4 of 16 bootstrap to percent and added some demo colors and heights) and set   `.ctr-panel {float:right; width=75%;}`
This seems to be, what you are looking for. Right!?

Comment: I feel silly for not thinking to mess with the `.ctr-panel` class.